# How to scan for suspicious php files on filesystem

Tags: filesystem, php, search, malware

As in the title, I would like to scan some directories on my local filesystem for suspicious (eg. obfuscated, system-calls, create-method calls, strange file names,... ) PHP-Files.

Is there a known tool which can help to find those files?